# Symfony Voters only for checking user permission?

Tags: symfony, symfony4-voter

Symfony Voters ([Documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html)) is for checking user permission for an entity (usually) :

> Security voters are the most granular way of checking permissions (e.g. "can this specific user edit the given item?")

Sut if I want to control the permissions on a module (for a user), the Symfony Voters are they adapted ? Example : can't edit module if module is valitated (`validated` = true on database) ?

**In summary, are voters exclusively tied to users or can they then play a more general role ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voters will do anything you "tell" them to. For convenience they receive the user as parameter, but you are not obliged to use it.